# Jordan Decompositions of Bounded Functionals over Continuous Functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

let $\Omega$ be (locally) compact Hausdorff space.

I Denote by $C(\Omega)$ normed space of all continuous (compactly supported) functions with sup norm
$$\| f \| = \sup_{x \in \Omega} f(x) $$
amd by $\mathfrak{M}(\Omega)$ space of finite (or regular) signed  measures .

When from  Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem it follows that where is a  linear isomorphism $I : \mathfrak{M}(\Omega) \to C^*(\Omega)$ defined by the rule 
$$ I(\mu)(f) = \int_\Omega f \, \mathrm{d}\mu. $$
I know that in case $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ I know  that (local) bounded variation norm on $\mathfrak{M}(\Omega)$ will make $I$ into isometry of normed spaces. The obvious norm for general case would be
push-forward
$$
\| \mu \| = \| I(\mu) \|
$$

> But aren't there a more meaningful norm on $\mathfrak{M}(\Omega)$ with the same property?
>   Why total variation $\| \mu \| = |\mu |(\Omega)$ norm won't work?

Secondly it's well known that signed measure can be represented as 
$$ \mu = \mu^+ - \mu^-, $$
where $\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$ are normal measures. When, as $I$ maps measures into positive functionals by her structure, every functional $F$ can be written for some signed measure $\mu$ as
$$ F = I(\mu) = I(\mu^+) - I(\mu^-) = F^+ - F^-, $$

where $F^+ $ and $F^{-}$ are positive functionals.

> What is the way to define $(F^+,F^-)$ just in terms of $F$ without any reference to $I$?
>   Basicly, I want to  be able to migrate this definition to other functional spaces which are not exactly $C(\Omega).$

It would be nice to know some direct references concerning  topic of positive-negative decomposition of functionals too. As it feels  like quiet a  standard topic. (I Just want to know  what  part of general functional analysis texts speaks about it is generally presented, because I haven't seen it yet).

Thanks for your time and attention.

--Addendum

The construction of $F^+$ for abstract normed space is obvious if positive cone $V_+$ spans $V$. As positive cone $V_+$ spans $V$ there exists a basis $\{e_a | a \in A \}$ of exclusively positive vectors for some (uncountable) set $A$ (This needs axiom of choice). Then every vector $v$ can be written as
$$
 v = \sum_{a \in A}v_ae_a
$$
with only finite number of non-zero $v_a$ .Then put
$$
F^+(v) = \sum_{a \in A} v_a (f(e_a))^+
$$
and 
$$F^-(v) = \sum_{a \in A} v_a (f(e_a))^- $$
From properties of Cones it follows that for every $v \in V$ coordinates $v_a > 0$ so this functionals are indeed positive. However, It seems that this functions are bounded functionals only if norm in $V$ is invariant to a change of signs of coordinates.

This properties hold for any finite-dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^n$ trivialy and for every inner product space which admits Schauder basis of positive elements. So if $H$ is such inner product space and where exists an embedding $E:V \to H$ which preserves positivity of an element the proposed construction will work ( extend pull-back of $F E^{-1}$ from $\mathrm{im} E$ to $H$ by Hahn-Banach theorem as $G$ . Then define $F^+ = G^+ E$ and $F^{-} =  G^{-} E$ ).

For $V = C(\Omega)$ role of $H$ can be played by Hilbert space $L_2(\Omega,\mu)$
where $\mu$ is a finite measure which is non-zero on every open set (Existence of such measure is another question).

This construction is bad for two reasons:

Firstly, it depends on "coordinates".

Secondly, It still relies on some external space when $V$ is not simple enough.

Comment: Conway's *A Course in Functional Analysis* has a couple of sections on positivity in an ordered vector space.  Then towards the end, positive linear functionals on $C^*$-algebras plays a large role in the representation theory of the algebras.

Comment: Aweygan , Thanks.  I will check it out.

Comment: Just "it requires the axiom of choice" does not merit the tag. The tag [axiom-of-choice] is meant for questions explicitly discussing the role of the axiom in definitions and proofs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found correct decomposition in this [real analysis post by Terence Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/02/245b-notes-12-continuous-functions-on-locally-compact-hausdorff-spaces/) in Lemma 9. Jordan decomposition of functions.

It seems that this construction will work in every ordered normed vector space  $V$ such that $V = V_+ + V_+$ which holds if $V_+$ is cofinal.